# IN google tag manager setup page domain should be with www, without or both?

Tags: google-tag-manager

IN google tag manager setup page domain should be with www, without or both?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your site!

All the domains are there for are to help provide default values/suggestions etc later on when you are setting up your containers - as far as I am aware it doesn't have any functional effect on your container and are optional.

Some sites will be set up to automatically redirect users from www.domain.com to domain.com, or domain.com to www.domain.com etc.   If your site does this then enter that URL appropriately, otherwise I'd personally opt for including the www.